# Can I use Win 2k8 R2 as an IPSEC client?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ipsec, windows-firewall

I'm trying to connect a win server 2008 R2 box to a juniper ssg firewall using a client-to-gateway IPSEC VPN.

I tried to set it up in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, but the connection doesn't appear to work. Would love to hear from someone who's made this work.

Thanks!

The settings I'm using are:

```
Endpoint 1: [ip address of this machine]  
Endpoint 2: [ip range of the machines behind the firewall at the other end]  
Auth mode: require inbound and outbound 
Method: PSK Key: [###] 
Profile: Domain, Private, Public
```

Use IPsec tunneling, apply authorization.

```
Local tunnel endpoint: [ip address of this machine]
Remote tunnel endpoint: [ip address of remote firewall]
```

My ISP gave me detailed settings -- AES128, SHA1 -- but I don't see anywhere to enter them. Also, they gave me Phase 2 settings, but the connection setup wizard won't allow Phase 2 config in conjunction with PSK.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the Advanced Settings tab. But here's a quick walk through.

**1. Choose set up a vpn in the start menu**

[image: Start menu]

**2. Follow the wizard. Select "Don't Connect Now"**
[image: ms vpn wizard]

**3. Browse to network connections in Control Panel and Right-click your new connection and choose properties**
[image: network connections]

**4. Go to the security tab and select IPSEC.**
[image: Security tab]

**5. Click advanced settings and enter your PSK (Pre-Shared Key)**
[image]

You may need to adjust your settings a bit from there, but that should get you most of the way.

Comment: I have the same problem with nearly same settings as Jesse already specified: I need to establish a connection from a Windows Server 2008 R2 to a remote server via IPSec. SLY, I tried your proposed solution to enter the PSK but cannot figure out where to set all the other things like encryption, hash function etc. for phases 1 and 2. Can you provide a complete setup for the exemplary settings Jesse specified? Thanks a lot.

Comment: L2TP/IPsec != IPsec. From memory, Windows  doesn't do a plain IPsec VPN client. IKEv2 might be a closer fit (as of Win7), otherwise a third-party client like Shrewsoft might be an option.